# An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time when calling FatSecret Sharp API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

I'm attempting to make a basic ASP.NET application that makes a call to the Fatsecret API using a wrapper called FatSecret Sharp, however am getting this error when I try to make the server side method call from my JS script, and I'd like to determine how I can successfully use this wrapper to create a web application.

You'll notice that the API call from the wrapper explicitly mentions that it is "synchronous", so I assume that's what's throwing the error, I just don't know why, or how I can use that call successfully with a web application.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
var jsonData;

function search() {
    var element = document.getElementById("searchField")
    var searchTerm = element.value;

    callAJAX("FoodSearchExample", searchTerm);
}

function callAJAX(requestMethod, term) {
    var pageMethod = "default.aspx/" + requestMethod;

    $.ajax({
    url: pageMethod,
    data: JSON.stringify({ searchTerm : term }),
    type: "POST",  
    contentType: "application/json",       
    dataType: "JSON",  
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (result) {
        ajaxCallback(result.d);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});

return false;
}

function ajaxCallback(serverResponse) {
    if (serverResponse !== "loadLocations") {
        //jsonData = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
        alert(serverResponse);
    }
    else
        alert("error");
}
```

C#

```
namespace HELP_Testing
{

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static string consumerKey = "key (removed from question)";
    private static string consumerSecret = "secret (removed from question)";

    [WebMethod]
    public static string FoodSearchExample(string searchTerm)
    {
        FoodSearch foodSearch = new FoodSearch(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        string str = "";

        var response = foodSearch.GetResponseSynchronously(new FoodSearchRequest()
        {
            SearchExpression = searchTerm
        });

        List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();

        if (response.HasResults)
        {               
            Food f;

            foreach (var food in response.foods.food)
            {
               f = new Food();
               f.FoodId = food.food_id;
               f.FoodType = food.food_type;
               f.FoodName = food.food_name;
               foods.Add(f);
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No results from term");

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        str = serializer.Serialize(foods);

        return str;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="True"  CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="HELP_Testing._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/default.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <title>Healthy Eating Life Planner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="Food Search" id="searchField" />
        <button type="submit" onclick="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The full error message is:

An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started with an asynchronous handler or module
or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page
is marked Async = true. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an 'async void' method, which is generally
unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [the problem is in `GetResponseSynchronously`](https://fatsecretsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/FatSecretSharp.Services/Common/BaseFatSecretGetService.cs). Polling for completion is a very questionable approach.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. One is to throw out the FatSearch CSharp library and use `HttpClient` to write to their JSON API. This approach is cleaner, but means you'll have to write more code.

The other approach is to [wrap the sort-of-EBAP APIs from FatSearch CSharp as `async`-compatible methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP). In this case, the important members are `GotResult`, `GotError`, and `StartRequestAsync`. Note that your web method will become `async`.

Comment: Additional sidenote: turns out the wrapper has an async option but we haven't figured out how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling 
public Task GetResponseSynchronously(TRequest request) like the sample console App suggests, in a Web context such as MVC, it is better to add an async method such as the one I successfully wrote below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the response Asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
    /// <returns>A parsed response, or throws an exception.</returns>
    public async Task<TResponse> GetResponseAsynchronously(TRequest request)
    {

        var requestUrl = CreateRequestUrl(request);

        HttpClient APIRequest = new HttpClient();

        var response = await APIRequest.GetAsync(requestUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string downloadedString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        var result = ConvertClientResultString(downloadedString);                      

        return result;
    }
```

It's important to note that to obtain a seamless result, you will need to alter the BaseJsonService.cs of the Service4u2Lib by adding a response processing method like the one below:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Handles the client result string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="downloadedString">The downloaded string.</param>
    public TResultType ConvertClientResultString(string downloadedString)
    {
        // Check for html doctype and report error if found.
        int takeLength = downloadedString.Length > 20 ? 20 : downloadedString.Length;
        if (downloadedString.Substring(0, takeLength).Contains("!DOCTYPE html"))
            HandleClientError(new NotSupportedException("The service call returned html and not json"));

        var result = new TResultType();

        string json = downloadedString;

        if (result is IJSONMassager)
        {
            json = ((IJSONMassager)result).MassageJSON(downloadedString);
        }

        if (result is IJSONSelfSerialize<TResultType>)
        {
            result = ((IJSONSelfSerialize<TResultType>)result).SelfSerialize(json);
        }
        else
            result = JsonHelper.Deserialize<TResultType>(json);

        if (GotResult != null)
            GotResult(this, new EventArgs<TResultType>() { Argument = result });

        return result;
    }
```

Basically we reshuffle the existing objects to make them work with an HTTPClient object which can handle requests using the .ConfigureAwait(false); method which ensures that the callback happens.